# Broken link issues from w3c link checker

Tags: html, validation, hyperlink, w3c-validation

When I check my website with W3C link checker, The checker shows:

Status: **403 Forbidden**

"**The link is forbidden! This needs fixing. Usual suspects: a missing index.html or Overview.html, or a missing ACL**"

But that link is working fine. How can I resolve this issue from that link checker?

Screenshot:
  [image]

Comment: Do you have a link to the fully results of your test? or a screen shot? anything that will shed some more light on the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That issue is usually used by over-zealous security filtering which either assumes that all bots are evil or that all bots using certain libraries are evil.

The checklink software uses the LWP library which often finds its way onto such blacklists. The two ways to get checklink to pass the link are:

- Download [checklink](http://search.cpan.org/dist/W3C-LinkChecker/), edit its user-agent string, then run it from your local system and not the W3C servers. (See also: [installing CPAN modules](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html).)
- Change the security filtering on the server the link is pointing to (this obviously requires that you have access to that server)

Alternatively, you can check the links manually each time you perform a check.

Comment: Hi I have another problem, When I use W3c validater for checking my site it shows "required attribute "alt" not specified" and also "

The attribute given above is required for an element that you've used, but you have omitted it. For instance, in most HTML and XHTML document types the "type" attribute is required on the "script" element and the "alt" attribute is required for the "img" element.

Typical values for type are type="text/css" for <style> and type="text/javascript" for <script>.
"  How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @Sujanth — That's a completely new question (about a completely different piece of software) and you should ask a new question as a question and not as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Its not always possible to follow all the standards.
If you have tested that the link is working fine than go ahead.